# This site has been updated in background

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

**Problem** :I am getting one extra notification when my react-app is in open in background in browser .that extra notification comes with message "This site has been updated in background" .

I am implementing push notification functionality for background notification using firebase cloud messaging.
what I have tried so far. I have tried using returning self.registration.showNotification also
tried with setTimeout of 1sec and then returned self.registration.showNotification through promise.

**what are the solution that I don't want .**
1.remove onBackgroundMessage itself FCM will trigger automatic
notification.
2. by listening push event . because I have foreground notification
also if I use push event listener and use show-notification init my
foreground notification also converted to background .

Observation : if react-app is not in background mean tab itself is closed than it is working fine but when tab is open and chrome or Edge in background it triggers 1 extra notification with message "This site has been updated in background".

```js
//firebase-messaging-sw.js

// Scripts for firebase and firebase messaging
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js');


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: '',
  appId: '',
  measurementId: ''
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
  if (payload ) {
    const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
      body: payload.data.body,
      data: payload.data.clickEvent
    };

    return  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
  }
});
```

Comment: self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
  
  messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
    const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
      body: payload.data.body
    };

    return event.waitUntil(
      self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions)
    );
  });
});   I am able to fix the issue using this script .

Comment: Is this instead of the current messaging.onBackgroundMessage?